# Правила пунктуации при перечислении

Tags: пунктуация, терминология, перечисление

Прошу подсказать о правилах пунктуации в предложениях, подобных следующему:

> Образование мягкотканной плотности(,) овоидной конфигурации(,) с
> четкими(,) ровными контурами(,) без перифокальных изменений.